# Magento pack promotion with fixed price

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

What I need is to set a pack promotion with a fixed price. eg: Giving a pack with 1 shirt, 1 trouser and 1 skirt for 500

Comment: With cart rules this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Just go for it

- Create a bundle product as you want with fix price as 500
- Create bundle option with Input Type radio and assign first product only with default qty 1
- Choose Is required as yes and default for that product
- Create another bundle option like same above step for second product and for 3rd product also

This will give you 3 option only with required and default in frontend, so user can not choose/update any option.

**Note:** It will display 3 group title in frontend that you have to manage from css.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any way to achieve this without creating bundle items. ?  Using cart rule I able to set the conditions but giving different items altogether with a fixed price is not possible with cart rule. I am looking for some extra option in cart rule that can sort out this fixed price.

Comment: @JicksonJohnsonKoottala In that case you have to create 2 diifferent product with zero (0) price and according to cart rule you have to add these product in cart with the help of observer.